# Do the two r.v. generate the same σ-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_{n})$ be a sequence of independent integrable random variables and $Y_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{k}X_{j}$. How to prove that $\sigma(Y_{1},\cdots Y_{n})=\sigma(X_{1},\cdots X_{n}),\forall n\in\mathbb{N}?$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: I will add that if we know that $X_i \ne 0$ (in this case we may write $X_n = f_n(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) ) $  then the claim is true, otherwise there is a problem that I already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not correct, but we can prove that $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \subset \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) $.

For $n \le N$ we have $Y_n = f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, hence $\sigma(Y_n) \subset \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \subset \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_N) $. Thus $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_N) \subset \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_N) $.

Example of situation when $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \ne \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) $:
$X_1 = 0$, $X_i$, $i \ge 2$ - nondegenerate i.i.d. Then $Y_n = 0 $, $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ is trivial and  $\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) $ is not trivial.

Comment: Ok,  $Y_{1}=X_{1}$ so $\sigma(Y_{1})=\sigma(X_{1})$, $Y_{2}=X_{1}+X_{1}X_{2}$ so $\sigma (Y_{1})\subset \sigma (X_{1},X_{2})$ and so on and $Y_{n}=f(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})$ so $\sigma(Y_{n})\subset\sigma(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})$ and how we get from these that $\sigma(Y_{1},\cdots,Y_{n})\subset\sigma(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n})?$

Comment: By definition $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ is a sigma-algebra, generated by the set $M$ of events $ \{ Y_i  \in B \}$, where $B$ is a Borel set. We have $M \subset \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. It follows that $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) = \sigma(M) \subset \sigma(\sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)) = \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n) $. I used the next fact: if M is a set of events and $M \subset \sigma^*$ where $\sigma^*$ is a sigma-algebra then it's easy to see that $\sigma(M) \subset \sigma(\sigma^*)$. But $\sigma(\sigma^*) = \sigma^*$. Hence $ M \subset  \sigma(\sigma^*) = \sigma^*$.

Comment: It is very complicated for me.... It was explained at school somehow like this: $\forall B_{n}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),\exists C_{n}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $[(Y_{1},\dots Y_{n})\in B_{n}]=[(X_{1},\dots X_{n})\in C_{n}]$ where $C_{n}=f^{-1}(B_{n})$ Is this correct? How does it prove the inclusion?

Comment: Ok. We know that $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) $ is some continuous function of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, denote if by $f$. Hence $\{  (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \in B_n \} = \{  f(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in B_n) \}$. But the latter event is equal to $ (X_1, \ldots, X_n) = f^{-1}(B_n)$. It's sufficient to notice that $f^{-1}$(Borel set) is (an another) Borel set for continuous $f$. I used the nexf fact: pre-image of a Borel set by a continuous function is a Borel set. See, e.g.: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806762/is-the-pre-image-of-a-borel-set-by-a-continuous-function-a-borel-set-is-it-an-o

Comment: I am lost at the beginning. I understand $Y_{n}=f(X_{1},\cdots,X_{n}).$ But $(Y_{1},Y_{2},\cdots,Y_{n})=f(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})?$ I would say $(Y_{1},Y_{2},\cdots,Y_{n})=(f(X_{1}),f(X_{1},X_{2}),\cdots ,f(X_{1},\cdots, X_{n}))$

Comment: @dena, your statement is similar to mine. Because what does it mean that $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n) =f(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$? It means that if we know $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, then we may compute $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: Let $X_1=0$. Then $Y_n=0%$ for all $n$. So $\sigma (Y_1,Y_1,...,Y_n)=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.  But $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is non-trivial for any i.i.d sequence $(X_n)_{n\geq 2}$ of non-degenerate random variables.